# Can you set an ENV variable to different values for different steps in a Jenkins freeStyleJob?

Tags: jenkins, environment-variables, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-job-dsl

Is it possible in a Jenkins DSL free-style job to set the same environment variable to different values for each step of the job?

For example, I have a Jenkins Free-style job that calls a bash script twice in 'steps':

```
freeStyleJob('Myjob') {
    environmentVariables {
        groovy(readFileFromWorkspace('env/my_env.groovy'))
        env('CONFIG', '/home/config.json')
        // I would like to redefine CONFIG to equal the following on the second call to test.sh
        // env('CONFIG', '/home/other_config.json')
    }
    steps {
        shell(readFileFromWorkspace('scripts/test.sh'))
        shell(readFileFromWorkspace('scripts/test.sh'))
    }
}
```

For the first step of the job, I want the value of the env variable 'CONFIG' in test.sh to be '/home/config.json'.

However, in the second call to test.sh, I want to update 'CONFIG' to be '/home/other_config.json'.

Is it possible to redefine an environment variable between steps like this?

Comment: Why not simply add a direct step to load the relevant json config file for the first and second call to test.sh? 
```groovy
    steps {
        env('CONFIG', '/home/config.json')
        shell(readFileFromWorkspace('scripts/test.sh'))
        env('CONFIG', '/home/other_config.json')
        shell(readFileFromWorkspace('scripts/test.sh'))
    }
```
?

Comment: ```freeStyleJob('Myjob') {
    environmentVariables {
        groovy(readFileFromWorkspace('env/my_env.groovy')
    }
    steps {
        env('CONFIG', '/home/config.json')
        shell(readFileFromWorkspace('scripts/test.sh'))
        env('CONFIG', '/home/config.json')
        shell(readFileFromWorkspace('scripts/test.sh'))
    }
}``` fails to compile

Comment: ```ERROR: (unknown source) No signature of method: javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.step.StepContext.env() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String) values: [CONFIG, /home/config]```

Comment: my bad. you could try putting each step in a separate stage also by making use of `withEnv` directive like `withEnv(["CONFIG=/home/other_config.json"]){..}` within the curly braces keep your script calls.